# Pass JavaScript variable as a4j:jsFunction action method argument without need for a4j:param and additional property

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a js variable that I would like to pass as a parameter to my backend action class - I am using JSF + RichFaces and Java.

Now I know there is an a4j:jsFunction component I can use that creates a js function for me to call, and I know there is an a4j:param but the only examples I can find are ones that set a managed bean, which I would like to skip.

I have a jsFunction like below

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="someFunction" action="#{action.performAction}">
    <a4j:param name="jsonData" />
</a4j>
```

I call this function on page load, document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsVariable = do logic....
    someFunction(jsVariable);
});
```

Finally I have a back end action class in java

```
public void performAction(String jsonData) {
    System.out.println(jsonData);
}
```

As shown I would like to be able to pass the jsVariable as a parameter to a backend action method.

Is the only way to create a property on the backend for the jsFunction to set?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a4j:actionparam inside tag a4j:jsfunction for details refer below link
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesCookbookJsFunctionJson